# Remove unecssary directories in path name constructed with os.join

Tags: python

In Python when I print directory path constructed with `os.join` I get something like this :

```
rep/rep2/../rep1
```

Is there a way to get only this :

```
rep/rep1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `os.path.normpath()` collapses redundant separators and up-references.

`os.path.realpath()` converts the path to a canonical path, which includes eliminating '..' components, but it also eliminates symlinks.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.relpath("rep/rep2/../rep1", start="")
'rep/rep1'
```

Or [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normpath("rep/rep2/../rep1")
'rep/rep1'
```